# How to record a button push on a text file in android studio?

Tags: android

I have an app to record bunch of values to a text file in defined time intervals (values are grabbed from a Bluetooth device). So I need to add "1" or "0" to the text file  with other values depending whether button is pushed or not while recording those values.

```
fun saveToTextFile( x: Float, y: Float, z: Float, x1: Float, y1:Float, z1:Float, temp: Float) {

    getLocation()

    try {

        val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/BTH"
        val folder = File(path)
        if (!folder.exists()) folder.mkdirs()

        val file = File(folder, fileName)
        if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile()
        //open file for writing
        val out = OutputStreamWriter(FileOutputStream(file, true))

        out.write(convertValesToString(x, y, z, x1, y1, z1, temp))
        out.write("\n")

        //close file
        out.close()

    } catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

Comment: Its a vague question, copy the code of your Activity/Fragment too from where you are trying to call your method saveToTextFile

Answer (score 0):

Please use this listener on ur button.

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener { saveToTextFile(..put ur data here...) }
```

Comment: actually I need to add "1" or "0" to the text file depending on the button push state since the other values (x, y, z... etc) will recorded continuously in defined time intervals. (eg- time1 | xvalue | yvalue| .... |buttonpush1)

Comment: Then create a button class extension with a state initialized as = 0 and when setOnClickListener is called update that value to 1. This way u can reuse the button in every layout u need it